# Cálculo da reputação da página de ranking

Tags: bug, reputação

Estava vendo a [página de ranking de reputação](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/526/year/pt-stackoverflow/2020-01-01/) e me deparei com uma situação estranha: um usuário tem mais reputação no ano, que a total!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faz sentido? Como são calculados esses dois totais?

Comment: Acredito que do lado direito seja a reputaçao ganha, desconsiderando downvotes recebidos (-2), downvotes dados (-1) e usuários que foram removidos (e os pontos que você perdeu com isso). No meu caso (menos de 2k de reputação), creio que edições sugeridas desfeitas (-2) também não sejam consideradas ali

Comment: Seria isso: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/401803 ?

Comment: pode ser isso mesmo @hkotsubo, o que chamou lá de *"private reputation events"*, como downvotes e posts removidos

Comment: faz sentido @RafaelTavares. Acabou ficando de exemplo na pergunta, sorry :)

Comment: @hkotsubo pode postar como resposta pf?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Demorei um pouco pra responder pq estava procurando referências no FAQ oficial, mas no fim acho que só tem aquela pergunta mesmo. Enfim, tá lá a resposta...

Comment: eu mudei o titulo da pergunta pra ficar mais fácil de achar caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida no futuro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única referência que encontrei foi [esta pergunta no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141628/401803), cuja [resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/401803) diz que este comportamento é normal ("*by design*").

O que acontece é que a terceira coluna ("*Total reputation*") refere-se à pontuação atual da pessoa, podendo ter um pequeno *delay* de 24 horas ([*talvez por motivos de cache*](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)).

Já a quarta coluna ("*Year reputation*") é o quanto a reputação se alterou durante o ano, excluindo os chamados "eventos privados" (aqueles não são mostrados aos outros usuários, como *posts* deletados e votos negativos dados pelo usuário).

Como a terceira coluna inclui os eventos privados (até para poder calcular corretamente o valor final), há esta diferença no resultado.